# Reshape column to row in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataset with 30 rows and 1 columns. What i want is to convert each elements in 10 rows and put it in 10 columns in Pandas. So at the end the dataset would be transformed to three rows and ten columns. Can any one direct me how i can do it?

It is not easy to show 30 elements so below is the smaller case:

```
   col1
```

0    |    94.024

1    |    94.039

2    |    93.986

3    |    94.003

4    |    93.969

5    |    93.954

What I would like to have is:

```
 col1      col2      col3
```

0 | 94.024  |  94.039  |  93.986

1 | 94.003  | 93.969   |  93.954

Answer (score 1):

**Toy Example**

```
pd.DataFrame(
     df.Col1.values.reshape(-1, 3),
     columns=['col%s' % i for i in range(1, 4)]
)

   col1  col2  col3
0    11    12    13
1    14    15    16
```

**30 Row Example**

```
pd.DataFrame(
     df.Col1.values.reshape(3, 10),
     columns=['col%s' % i for i in range(1, 11)]
)
```

Comment: thanks! can it be more dynamic cause my actual data is not integer so the 'for loop' should be done by indexing i guess but i don't know how?!

Comment: @user8034918 I don't know what that means.  If the problem is more complicated than this, you should explain that in the question.  Show a complete example that demonstrates what you'd like to see.  Also read this [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape your data to 3 columns and construct a new DF and rename the columns.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,3))
  .pipe(lambda x: x.rename_axis(lambda x: x+1,1))
  .add_prefix('col')
Out[555]: 
     col1    col2    col3
0  94.024  94.039  93.986
1  94.003  93.969  93.954
```